# C Hexadecimal Memory locations

Tags: c, memory, hex

Okay, I'm working on learning C and working with some memory locations.

Assume the sizeof(double) is 8

and we have a double dbl_array[5] with a memory location of 0x7fffffffe360.

What would the memory location be for &(dbl_array[4])?

When running locally I can see that the location goes from b34b0 to b34d0, but I'm stuck on how to apply this to the assumed location.

Any tips would be amazing!

Comment: b34d0h - b34b0h =  20h = 32 = # of octets from the base of the array. That's right inline with your being 4 doubles deep in the array at 8 octets each.

Comment: Are you asking how hexadecimal works?

Comment: @user3386109 I semi understand how they work, but what I'm stuck on is applying the change in the location from the base of dbl_array ( ..... b34b0) to &(dbl_array[4]) (.... b34d0) to the assumed location of 0x7fffffffe360

Comment: Given that a `double` is 8 bytes, if `array[0]` is at address `x`, then `array[1]` is at  `x + 8`, `array[2]` is  at `x + 16`, and so on. So all you need to do is take your memory location, and add 8 a few times until you get to `array[4]`. And that's convenient in hexadecimal because `0x8 + 0x8 = 0x10`.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the address in bytes as `base + 4*sizeof(double)`. So `0x7fffffffe360 + 4*8`.

Answer (score 0):

> What would the memory location be for `&(dbl_array[4])`?

Without knowing the type of computer and/or operating system running this program, this question cannot be answered; it is only possible to say which address this element would have on 99% of all computers:

If `X` is an array of the data type `Y` and the address of the element `X[n]` is `Z`, the address of the element `X[n+1]` is `Z+sizeof(Y)`.

For this reason, the address of the element `X[n+M]` is `Z+M*sizeof(Y)`.

The address of an array is the address of element `X[0]`.

Now simply take a calculator that can calculate hexadecimal numbers and perform the following calculation: `0x7fffffffe360 + 4 * 8`

However, there are counterexamples where the address calculation is done differently: The "`huge`" memory layout on x86-16 for example...